# How to clear shell in ielm?

Tags: comint, inferior-lisp

I am trying the clear the inferior emacs lisp mode(ielm) buffer.
Solutions applicable to shell are not applicable here - the `erase-buffer` command says "Test is read only"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`inferior-emacs-lisp-mode` (aka `ielm`), like various other subshell modes in Emacs, derives from `comint-mode`, a general COMmand INTerpreter. This means that `ielm` inherits a lot of `comint`'s functionality and key bindings.

Emacs 25 added the command `comint-clear-buffer`, by default bound to `C-c M-o`, which works in any `comint` derivative, including `ielm`.

In older Emacsen I propose two solutions:

1. Define `comint-clear-buffer` and its binding yourself:

   ```el
   (with-eval-after-load 'comint
     (unless (fboundp 'comint-clear-buffer)
       (defun comint-clear-buffer ()
         "Clear the comint buffer."
         (interactive)
         (let ((comint-buffer-maximum-size 0))
           (comint-truncate-buffer)))

       (define-key comint-mode-map "\C-c\M-o" #'comint-clear-buffer)))
   ```

   or, in even older Emacsen than that:

   ```el
   (eval-after-load 'comint
     (lambda ()
       (unless (fboundp 'comint-clear-buffer)
         (defun comint-clear-buffer ()
           "Clear the comint buffer."
           (interactive)
           (let ((comint-buffer-maximum-size 0))
             (comint-truncate-buffer)))

         (define-key comint-mode-map "\C-c\M-o" #'comint-clear-buffer))))
   ```
2. Make the best of what is available:

   1. `M-x mark-whole-buffer` (`C-x h`) - Mark whole buffer.
   2. `M-x comint-kill-region` - Kill buffer contents, including read-only prompts.
   3. `M-x ielm-return` (`RET`/`<return>`) - Create new prompt.

Comment: there is no comint-clear-buffer command, and no C-c M-o key binding

Comment: @DraifKroneg Sorry about that, it seems this function was only added in Emacs 25. I'll update my answer.